# Как открыть в окне vim терминал

Tags: консоль, vim

[image: vim]

Vim разбил на 3 окна - горизонтально и вертикально. Но не могу найти инфу как первое окно(где курсор) превратить в терминал. Чтобы был терминал для запуска make и прочего. То есть работа с директорией.

Comment: Возможно [здесь](https://gist.github.com/mislav/5189704) вы найдёте ответ на свой вопрос...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если у вас свежий *Vim* (8.0 и новее) и он скомпилирован
с опцией `+terminal`, то это довольно просто:

```
This feature is for running a terminal emulator in a Vim window.  A job can be
started connected to the terminal emulator. For example, to run a shell: 
     :term bash

Or to run build command: 
     :term make myprogram

The job runs asynchronously from Vim, the window will be updated to show
output from the job, also while editing in another window.
```

[Документация](https://vimhelp.org/terminal.txt.html).

Чтобы посмотреть версию *Vim* и опции компиляции:

```sh
$ vim --version
```